# multiple columns with same header tallying within pandas across multiple sheets/dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a workbook like this, with multiple sheets all looking the same. In my actual data, the repeating size color material on each sheet goes on for five iterations each.

```
name        size    color   material        size    color   material    size    color   material
bob         m       red     coton           m       yellow  cotton      m       green   dri-fit
james       l       green   dri-fit         l       green   cotton      l       red     cotton
```

in excel I have taken the columns (minus the names) and made them into one long sheet - with only three columns. copying and pasting from all sheets into one. It takes forever. This way i can format it as a table and filter out for totals.

I need a way to tally how many specific shirts of each we have. 34 red m cotton shirts, 50 small ... etc.

I personally couldn't think of a way to do this within pandas - but i'm fairly confident a way to do this exists. Anyone care to give me an idea as to what a solution for this in Pandas might look like?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

You need to `set_index` to column `name`. `Groupby` each consecutive 3 columns. Finally, `pd.concat` on all groups and `reset_index`

```
num_group = 3 
df = df.set_index('name')
gp = df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // num_group, axis=1)
pd.concat([g for _, g in gp]).reset_index()

Out[2270]:
    name size   color material
0    bob    m     red    coton
1  james    l   green  dri-fit
2    bob    m  yellow   cotton
3  james    l   green   cotton
4    bob    m   green  dri-fit
5  james    l     red   cotton
```

---

As you said your real data has repeating of 5 groups, so set `num_group = 5` to run with your real data.

Answer (score 0):

We can do with `wide_to_long`

```
s=df.columns.to_series()
df.columns=df.columns+s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str)
pd.wide_to_long(df,['size','color','material'],i='name0',j='drop')
Out[225]: 
           size   color material
name0 drop                      
bob   0       m     red    coton
james 0       l   green  dri-fit
bob   1       m  yellow   cotton
james 1       l   green   cotton
bob   2       m   green  dri-fit
james 2       l     red   cotton
```

Comment: seems like a very good solution, however if my columns names are actually : (Size 1, material, sleeve, color ... Size 2, material.2, sleeve.2, color.2 ... Size 3, material.3  etc)  i assume it isnt possible to use wide to long since the names on the first set are the stubname exactly? @WeNYoBen